# Py.Test aborts when (py)ROOT is imported

Tags: python, pytest, pyroot

I've a problem unit testing Python code, which uses the (py)ROOT package. It simply aborts collecting the tests when there is a line `import ROOT` in one of the scripts.

Does anybody have an idea what's going on?

```
foo@bar ~/project/dir                                                [19:21:17] 
(project)> $ py.test -v                                             [±master ●]
============================= test session starts ==============================
platform darwin -- Python 2.7.6 -- py-1.4.25 -- pytest-2.6.3 -- /path/to/.virtualenvs/project/bin/python
collecting 0 items[1]    16520 abort      py.test -v
```

Comment: Does it work outside `pytest`? In other words, does `python -c "import ROOT"` work?

Comment: @BrunoOliveira yes of course, that works fine! I use that module every now and then…

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue by adding the PyROOT bindings to `export $PYTHONPATH` in my .bashrc. The locally set PYTHONPATH was ignored. A solution is copying or linking the ROOT.py and libPyROOT.so files to the appropriate Python directory in /usr/lib. More details in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33130000/4753851