# Enable PyROOT Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, pyroot

I downloaded **madpgraph5**, but when I run it I get the following error:

```
 ERROR: ROOT file called 'ROOT.py' or 'ROOT.pyc' is not found
 ERROR: Please check that ROOT is properly installed.
```

When I try `locate ROOT.py` and `locate ROOT.pyc`, I get nothing.

I have **root 5.34** installed and it runs smoothly. I also have **python 2.7.6** installed.

I downloaded **rootpy**, but have no idea how to include and enable **PyROOT**. I searched and I think I have to edit something to do with the path in **bashrc**, but before I do it I need to be sure of what I am doing.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Maybe this [post](https://root.cern.ch/drupal/content/how-use-use-python-pyroot-interpreter) sheds some light on your problem.

Answer (score 2):

You have probably figured out how to use it already, so just in case someone else stumbles over this question.

First make sure you built ROOT with Python support, `root-config --features` should list python.

There are a few possibilities how to successfully use `import ROOT` in Python:

1. Add `export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:$ROOTSYS/lib` to your .bashrc where `$ROOTSYS` is the path to your ROOT installation.
2. The first way is the easiest, but in case you want to do something like `sudo pip install rootpy`, your local `$PYTHONPATH` isn't used. Another way is to copy the files `ROOT.py` and `libPyROOT.so` from path_to_root_installation/lib to /usr/lib/pythonX (replace X with your Python version).
3. Similar to the method above. But in case you recompile ROOT or change something else, a symbolic link might be better: `sudo ln -s /path_to_root/lib/ROOT.py /usr/lib/pythonX/ROOT.py` and for libPyROOT.so as well.

Answer (score 0):

You should install `libroot-bindings-python-dev` -- it solves the issue.